# Crystal Reports: Boolean Issues

Tags: sql, postgresql, crystal-reports, odbc

I have been having a rather troubling issue with utilizing Crystal Reports pulling data through a PostgreSQL ODBC source.  It appears I have a boolean field that is showing up as a boolean in the database expert and pretty much everywhere in Crystal reports.  I have an if statement that I am trying to use that will either not function, or error out when using it.  When I browse the data, it is either a 1 or a 0, and is a string with the length of 5.
Trying to fix this has been problematic to say the least.

This one doesn't work (always pulls the name from client rather than client_contact)

```
if ({client_contact.bill_to_contact} = "1") Then
trim({client_contact.given_name} + ' ' + {client_contact.initial}) + ' ' + UpperCase({client_contact.surname})
else
trim({client.given_name} + ' ' + {client.initial}) + ' ' + UpperCase({client.surname})
```

This one errors out saying it requires a boolean at bill_to_contact (which is a boolean).

```
if {client_contact.bill_to_contact} Then
trim({client_contact.given_name} + ' ' + {client_contact.initial}) + ' ' + UpperCase({client_contact.surname})
else
trim({client.given_name} + ' ' + {client.initial}) + ' ' + UpperCase({client.surname})
```

I tried the eqv function I have CR version 12.0.0.683.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was an issue with the ODBC driver that I was using for the database.
It had a setting for "Booleans as Chars" that was turned on.
Fixed it, worked like a charm.

Much thanks anyhow for the type conversion tips!  They will be useful down the road I am sure.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the second function to:

```
if CBool(CDbl({client_contact.bill_to_contact})) Then
```

to force a numeric, then boolean conversion.  Somewhere along the way, Crystal Reports doesn't think it's a boolean or a number.

Comment: It throws an error saying a a number or currency is required.  If I try to cast to a double it is saying that a non-numeric value is present.

Comment: @MISMajorDeveloperAnyways - updated my answer; if that still doesn't work, you've got a value in there that can't be convertd to a numeric.

Comment: I have been looking in the database and there are only clearly defined true and false options...  I am completely stumped on this one.  Even older reports that utilize boolean record selection functions will not work on my version of Crystal Reports.